# SQL Developer extremely slow in windows 10

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded sql developer for windows 10 and while using sql developer data modeler whenever I click on a logical model entity I have built the program completely freezes . I am using `jdk-14.02 version` and `datamodeler-20.2.0.167.1538-x64` which I believe are the latest  . I would appreciate your help with this as I do not know how to navigate through this error . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Technically we support oracle JDK 8 and 11. How big is your logical model? Normally we like to see a jstack dump of the program to debug UI freezes

Comment: @thatjeffsmith My program runs now but I had to delete a big entity that for no reason spammed a column like 200 + times . Why is this happening ?

Comment: Spammed?:if you can provide more details, I can file a bug for you

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I had created an entity with a name column and after creating a 1-1 relation with another one i got the name column like 200 times . I deleted the complete relation and modified my model . I have no problem now .